# Pandas Python DataFrames: How to split dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, split, dataframe

I have a df

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(11,3))

           0         1         2
0   0.102645 -1.530977  0.408735
1   1.081442  0.615082 -1.457931
2   1.852951  0.360998  0.178162
3   0.726028  2.072609 -1.167996
4  -0.454453  1.310887 -0.969910
5  -0.098552 -0.718283  0.372660
6   0.334170 -0.347934 -0.626079
7  -1.034541 -0.496949 -0.287830
8   1.870277  0.508380 -2.466063
9   1.464942 -0.020060 -0.684136
10 -1.057930  0.295145  0.161727
```

How can I split this in a given number of subsections, lets say 2 for now.

Something like this

```
           0         1         2
0   0.102645 -1.530977  0.408735
1   1.081442  0.615082 -1.457931
2   1.852951  0.360998  0.178162
3   0.726028  2.072609 -1.167996
4  -0.454453  1.310887 -0.969910

           0         1         2
5  -0.098552 -0.718283  0.372660
6   0.334170 -0.347934 -0.626079
7  -1.034541 -0.496949 -0.287830
8   1.870277  0.508380 -2.466063
9   1.464942 -0.020060 -0.684136
10 -1.057930  0.295145  0.161727
```

Ideally I would like to use np.array_split(df, 2) but it throws an error as its not an array.

Is there a built in function to do this? I don't particularly want to use df.loc[a:b] because its difficult to calculate the start and end depending on the given number of sub-dataframes needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.  It should return an array of n sub-dataframes if concatenated would return the original dataframe in question.

```
import math

def split(df, n):
    size = math.ceil(len(df) / n)
    return [ df[i:i + size] for i in range(0, len(df), size) ]
```

Comment: Thanks for this but the only issue is the remainder. Split(df,2) for my df returns 3 sub dfs. Is there no way to use np.arry_split() some how as that handles remainders automatically.

Comment: If you're using Python 2.x, try changing the line to calculate size to `size = math.ceil(float(len(df)) / n)`

Comment: I have no idea what you have done but its working well, I'll run some more tests and let you know it goes but thanks!

Comment: Python 2.x, `/` will default to integer division if the 2 operands are integers.  In Python 3, it'll perform floating point division, which is required for the bucket size to be calculated properly.  So, that's why explicitly converting the dataframe length to a floating point number fixed your problem.